oauth2 authorization server TokenStore replacement (Spring Boot 3.1.0)
In old version of auth server (5.7) I have custom JwtTokenStore for caching and pre-check exists tokens (and for revoke). In new authorization server project I can't found any same solution. As an option I can try to use OAuth2TokenCustomizer but I think it's looks ugly. Is there a beautiful solution to this issue?

AFAIU, I don't think you can use OAuth2TokenCustomizer to check existing tokens or to revoke them. You can try adding a filter and do it or else it's better to write a custom AuthenticationProvider and plug it in front of the actual provider you use.

@SuvinNimnakaSukka I resolved problem by using ApplicationListener for success and error Authentication events

I see. Could you please explain how do you handle pre-checks with the event listener?

@SuvinNimnakaSukka I use gateway service what have acces for distributed cache with white list of tokens. that cache filling by authorization server. better to use black list and handle with logout URI but I can't due to exist architecture
